# unable to install this Program on Kubuntu 19.04

Tags: kubuntu

I am unable to install this application (Pointwise) on Kubuntu 19.04. I have installed this application on kubuntu 18.04 LTS and it was working properly.

I do not know whats wrong with new Kubuntu 19.04. Can anybody help me. I will really appreciate you. Please have a look on the attached picture.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can anybody help me  Please.

Comment: Do you have java installed properly?

Comment: I did not install java as I did not need to install it on Kubuntu 18.04 lts. If you think , How should I install java properly. Can you please guide me. I would really appreciate hour help.

Comment: To look up info I want to copy info from your picture to see if the package (*shared library object is the same in 18.04/19.04*) is available, but I cannot copy/paste from a picture... To get the most help you should provide *usable* text and not pictures from text.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dear guiverc for your comment. I am pasting the all the text lines from the terminal.

Comment: Unpacking JRE ...
Starting Installer ...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /media/kubuntu/DATA/PointWise.18.2.R2-SSQ/linux64/pw-V18.2R2-linux_x86_64-jre.sh.5054.dir/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1872)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)

Comment: at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:67)
        at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:47)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Util.load(Util.java:485)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.<clinit>(IOUtil.java:351)
        at sun.nio.ch.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:48)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.<clinit>(FileChannelImpl.java:1204)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.getChannel(RandomAccessFile.java:278)

Comment: at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.util.SingleInstance.check(SingleInstance.java:74)
        at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.util.SingleInstance.checkForCurrentLauncher(SingleInstance.java:31)
        at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.checkSingleInstance(UnixLauncher.java:88)
        at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:60)

Comment: Can anybody please help me. I have tried other linux distributions as well and have same issue.